# How can I update a YouTube Video? | PHP

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I try update a YouTube Video. I use the function at the site https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#update_a_video and I try to copy this in my code but if I call listVideos(), I get Google_Service_YouTube_VideoListResponse but I need a Google_Service_YouTube_Video. How can I get it?

My PHP Code:

```
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
$videoid = "******Video ID********";
$new = "******* TEXT *********";
$videoinfo = $youtube->videos->listVideos('snippet', array('id' => $videoid));
$videoSnippet = $videoinfo[0]['snippet'];
$description = $videoSnippet['description'] . $new;
$videoSnippet['description'] = $description;
$youtube->videos->update("snippet", $videoSnippet);
```

The Error:

```
: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to 
Google_Service_YouTube_Resource_Videos::update() must be an instance of 
Google_Service_YouTube_Video, instance of 
Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet given, called in 
P:\Apache24\htdocs\*********** on line 232 and defined in 
P:\Apache24\htdocs\*******\Google Api System\vendor\google\apiclient- 
services\src\Google\Service\YouTube\Resource\Videos.php:309 
Stack trace:
0 P:\Apache24\htdocs\*********: Google_Service_YouTube_Resource_Videos- 
>update('snippet', Object(Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet ))
1 P:\Apache24\htdocs\********\*********\index.php(438): 
require('P:\\Apache24\\htd...')
```

Comment: $videoid = "******Video ID********;

you have forgot to close with "
$videoid = "******Video ID********";

Comment: @g33k i forgot it only here in stackoverflow :) in my Code I write $videoid = "******Video ID********";

Comment: Is `$videoid` literally  `******Video ID********` or it's just here too?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use

```
  $video = $listResponse[0];
  $updateResponse = $youtube->videos->update("snippet", $video);
```

since in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#update_a_video)

```
// Since the request specified a video ID, the response only
      // contains one video resource.
      $video = $listResponse[0];
      $videoSnippet = $video['snippet'];
      $tags = $videoSnippet['tags'];

      // Preserve any tags already associated with the video. If the video does
      // not have any tags, create a new list. Replace the values "tag1" and
      // "tag2" with the new tags you want to associate with the video.
      if (is_null($tags)) {
        $tags = array("tag1", "tag2");
      } else {
        array_push($tags, "tag1", "tag2");
      }

      // Set the tags array for the video snippet
      $videoSnippet['tags'] = $tags;

      // Update the video resource by calling the videos.update() method.
      $updateResponse = $youtube->videos->update("snippet", $video);
```

Comment: Then I get the Error "code": 400,
"message": "The request metadata is invalid." but I think it's the Right way :)

Comment: the Error:            { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "youtube.video", "reason": "invalidVideoMetadata", "message": "The request metadata is invalid.", "locationType": "other", "location": "body" } ], "code": 400, "message": "The request metadata is invalid." } }

Comment: are you doing that 

// Check if an auth token exists for the required scopes
$tokenSessionKey = 'token-' . $client->prepareScopes();

Comment: // Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID
    // Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type.
    // This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and
    // video category.
    $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
    $snippet->setTitle("Test title");
    $snippet->setDescription("Test description");
    $snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));

Comment: I check the Auth Token and the $youtube->videos->listVideos('snippet', array('id' => $videoid)); request work. If my Token don't exist then I can't do it.

Comment: check that 
https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/channel_localizations.php